# How to map through array inside the object in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

I have tried

```js
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
//import usestack from './Usestack'

export default function Table() {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState();
    const [finalq, setFinalq] = useState();
    const [pagenumber, setPagenumber] = useState(1);
    const [ques, setQues] = useState();
  
    async function apicall(finalq, pagenumber){
        var res = await fetch(`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?page=${pagenumber}&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=${finalq}&site=stackoverflow`)
        var data = await res.json();
        setQues(data)
    }

    const setq = (e)=>{
        setQuery(e.target.value);
    }

    const submitq=()=>{
        setFinalq(query);
        setQuery(' ');
        setPagenumber(1);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        apicall(finalq,pagenumber);
    },[finalq, pagenumber])

    //console.log(ques); 

    return (
        <>
        <div>
            <input type='text' value={query} onChange={setq}/>    
            <button onClick={submitq}>Submit</button>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>User id</th>
                    <th>User name</th>
                    <th>Quetion</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {ques.items.map((i,key)=>(
                <div>samruddh</div>
            ))}
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

but it is not working, it just makes react page plain white
I have added the whole component and also so please check that.

I am fetching StackOverflow API with help of the input tag and button.

Comment: please check your console. as you print it in console. you did not use any html tag to show your data into page

Comment: What are you trying to do after mapping through your array? Are you updating your react state because I don't see that in the code you provided. As per that you're only logging the each element of the iteration to the console.

Comment: How does your object look like inside the array `items`. Add array here...

Comment: Could you add the whole component that you have this code in? With the one line you have here it is quite hard to help you since we have no idea what is going on

Comment: @TimmNL update question please check that

Comment: okay, so right now your code will crash since initially the value of `ques` is `undefined`. It will throw an error on `ques.items` since in the first render it will try to get `items` from `undefined`. Could you update the line to `ques?.items?.map` and see what happens next?

Comment: now it's not blank but react is not able to show array element {ques?.items?.map((i,key)=>(
                <h1>{i}</h1>
            ))}

Comment: Yes, the `i` variable that you are trying to display here is an object. React does not know how to display an object, which is why you get the next error. If you want to print the object, you can stringify it by `JSON.stringify(i)`.

Comment: if i do that then how can i go to particular field?

Answer (score 1):

I just used your code in the **below picture** and it shows exact output on right side:

[image: output]

But as you said you seeing `it just makes react page plain white` so you need to use something like below to show the output on your react page.

```
<div>
{ 
  objectName.items.map((i, key)=>{
     <div>{i}</div>
  });
}
</div>
```